# SQL: Subtraction Formula

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Im trying to write a formula in `SQL Server` to subtract the values of two columns which are `[Product-cost]` and `[Credit]` any idea ?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that both columns are of integer datatype

```
Select [Product-Cost], [Credit], ResultColumn = [Product-Cost] - [Credit] 
From YourTable
```

**EDIT**

I assume that you wanted to execute the formula after inserting a new record.

If you have this table

```
---------------------------------------------
| ID | Product_Cost | Credit | ResultColumn |
---------------------------------------------
|  1 |    300       |  200   | Formula Here |             
---------------------------------------------
```

Defining a trigger might help you.
Run this script.

```
Create Trigger CustomTriggerName on YourTable
For Insert,Update as
Begin
    Set NoCount On;
    Update YourTable set ResultColumn = (([product_Cost]-[Credit])/3600.0)* 5
    where ID = (Select ID from Inserted)
End
Go
```

Try to insert a record, assuming that your ID column is an identity column so no need to insert a value for it. So try running this script to check what happens next.

```
Insert into YourTable (Product-Cost,Credit) values(8000,800)
Go
Select * from YourTable
Go
```

There you can see an autocomputed value after inserting a record. Hope it helps :)

Comment: what I meant to do is to write a formula in the computed column specification to make the third column calculate the value

Comment: @Humam: When will the calculation happen? Is it during insert or during select? If you wanted it to happen during insert then a trigger will do but it doesn't make sense because you can do a query that will just compute for the result and there is no need of saving the result for it.

Comment: @ Ian Jasper Bardoquillo: it is something like this `((diff([product_Cost],[Credit])/(3600.0))*(5))` this is done in the table design view

Comment: @Humam: So this formula executes during insert?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [Product-cost] - [Credit] AS SubstractedValue
  FROM YourTable
 WHERE YourRestriction = True
```

Forgot to escape the column names.

For adding a computed column, look to this page to tell you how..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx

Comment: Product-cost must be in square brackets. Otherwise it'll processed as `Product` minus `cost`

Comment: what I meant to do is to write a formula in the computed column specification to make the third column calculate the value

Comment: @Humam That link should show you how to programmatically do a create column for a computed column.  Otherwise, you can do it through the gui as well.

Answer (score 0):

To add a computed column to the table, something like:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyCalculatedValue AS [Product-Cost] - [Credit]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this please
 sql_bdo = sql_bdo + " and (@Y - u.YearOfBirth) <=@tt";